# How to get bean validation error message from properties file?

Tags: java, maven, properties, bean-validation

I have the following regexp that I am using to validate an email;

```
@Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid Email")
private String email;
```

My problem is that I can't seem to get the message from  my ValidationMessage.properties file. It simply displays the string I place in the "". I tried the following:

```
message="{InvalidEmail}"
```

(there is a key pair called 'InvalidEmail' in the ValidationMessage.properties file)
but instead of collection the key pair value it simply prints out the string '{InvalidEmail}'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I can't seem to get the message from my ValidationMessage.properties file*

The filename must be exactly `ValidationMessages.properties`, with the plural `s`. It must also be placed in the root of the classpath and thus not in any subfolder/package.

In case you actually wanted to customize the default name/location of the properties file, then you need to head to implementation specific ways, because this is not (yet?) supported by the API. In case of Hibernate Validator refer to [section 4.2.1 ResourceBundleLocator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-resource-bundle-locator).

Comment: 11 years has passed.  Is it possible to customize the default, to use application.properties instead of ValidationMessages.properties?

Comment: If you're using Hibernate Validator as Bean Validation implementation, then yes: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-resource-bundle-locator